# getting a list inside of a list?

Tags: java

if i have a map set up like this:

```
Map<Fruit, Map<Double, ArrayList<Fruit>>> total = new HashMap<Fruit, Map<Double, ArrayList<Fruit>>>();
```

i can access the outer layer by doing:

```
for (Entry<Fruit, Map<Double, ArrayList<Fruit>>> entry : total.entrySet()) {
}
```

but how do i get a hold of `Map<Double, ArrayList<Fruit>>` (the inner map) ? .... can't seem to figure it out.

i thought i could do something like this:

```
for (Entry<Fruit, Map<Double, ArrayList<Fruit>>> entry : total.entrySet()) {
    for (Map<Double, ArrayList<Fruit>> entry2 : entry.getValue()) {

    }
}
```

can't use entry.getValue() here... but it is the value that contains the Double, ArrayList

but no luck yet... any ideas?

Comment: Define "no luck": what actually happens?

Comment: What about list.get(i).get(i) and so on?

Comment: Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

Comment: [`Map#values()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()) returns a `Collection` of the value elements in the map. `entry.getValue()` will return the `Map` object, from which you can get the `entrySet()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just apply the same you did for the outer Map, and retrieve the EntrySet.

```
for (Entry<Fruit, Map<Double, ArrayList<Fruit>>> entry : total.entrySet()) {
    for (Entry<Double, ArrayList<Fruit>> entry2 : entry.getValue().entrySet()) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    for ( Map<Double, ArrayList<Fruit> map : total.values()) { 

    }
```